# php echo sends markup and other details along with the actual data

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to create a service for login. When I tried with the dummy data i.e. by hardcoding the username and password then the result echoed to the ajax was correct, but the moment I got the value from $_POST[], I am getting alot of markup and other unnecessary details, even if I am echoing hardcoded integers.

```
echo 0;
```

the returned value is -

> ( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant password - assumed 'password' in /var/www/abhishekprakashWebService/web_service/login.php on line *10*
>   Call Stack
>   #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
>   10.1106122300{main}(  )../login.php**:**0
>   
>   
>   
>   ( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' in /var/www/abhishekprakashWebService/web_service/login.php on line *11*
>   Call Stack
>   #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
>   10.1106122300{main}(  )../login.php**:**0
>   
>   1

Here last '1' is should be the response and everything above it is not necessary. How can I remove it?

snippet of the php echo -

```
$proc = $conn->prepare("CALL sp_validate_login(?, ?, @isThere)");
$proc->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$proc->bindParam(2, $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$proc->execute();

$retVal = $conn->query("SELECT @isThere")->fetchAll()[0][0];
echo $retVal
```

Thanks

Comment: Change `error_reporting` level

Comment: Hey worked like charm when I added `error_reporting(0)`. I hope this is the best way to do it. Thanks for the prompt reply. :)

Comment: When you're accessing the $_POST[] data, you are calling it correctly? Eg: $_POST[password] would throw the undefined constant notice level message but $_POST['password'] wouldn't. That message typically means you've not quoted a parameter. Turning off error reporting just suppresses the message, it doesn't fix the actual issue.

Comment: @Cody, When I replaced $_POST[password] to $_POST["password"]. It worked. Thanks for pointing out the silly error. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Notices are there to warn you that you are doing something that is incorrect but not fatal - in this case using an undefined constant.

Changing the error reporting level is not a solution. You just hide the problem.

Look at lines 10 and 11 and see where you are using something that you have not yet defined then either define it or don't use it.

Comment: Password and username was undefined, when changed to string the warning was gone. :)